# dollar sign is shown in before any integer value rather than actual value when setcellvalue phpexcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using the below code to set the cell value, but it shows the output in the cell which is different than the original:

```
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("F2",'1234567890');

Output
$1,234,567,890.00
```

The actual output which I expect is `1234567890`, but I don't know why it is showing like this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need only integer number format ?

Comment: what cell type has been set?

Comment: you need to set cell format `$excel2->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F2')
->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_NUMBER);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add number format to your cell

`$excel2->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('F2') ->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberForm‌​at::FORMAT_NUMBER);`

For more information of cell styling have look [here](http://www.cmsws.com/examples/applications/phpexcel/Documentation/API/li_PHPExcel_Style.html) and look *Style classes* on left navigation links.

Answer (score 0):

Use number format and set format code as per your requirement. 
Try below code.

```
$excel2->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue("F2",'1234567890')->getNumberFormat()->SetFormatCode('#,##0');
```

Comment: He don't need comma